# How can I write a year to date formula?

Tags: qliksense

I need to write a set analysis to manage a year-to-date request.

So my table is:

```
Group1; Group2; Revenue; Qty
```

I would like to show

```
Group1; Group2; Revenue PY; Qty PY; Revenue CY; Qty CY
```

PY= Previous Year
CY= Current Year

So I need to write a set analysis to get

Revenue PY = Revenue from 1-jan-2022 to 19-may-2022
Revenue CY = Revenue from 1-jan-2023 to 19-may-2023

Set analysis I wrote, that doesn't work:

```
Sum({< [DatePrest] = {">=$(=Date(MonthStart(AddYears(Today(), -1)), 'YYYY-MM-DD'))<=$(=Date(Today() - 1, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))"} >} Revenue)
```

`DatePrest` is the date.

What is wrong ?

Comment: Please don't tag your titles, and format your code properly. See [ask].

Comment: I think you should use "YearStart" instead of "MonthStart" in your expression.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could use this expression for `[Revenue CY]` value:

```
=Sum({< [DatePrest] = {">=$(=Date(YearStart(Today()), 'M/D/YYYY'))<=$(=Date(Today() - 1, 'M/D/YYYY'))"} >} [Revenue])
```

And then this expression for `[Revenue PY]` value:

```
=Sum({< [DatePrest] = {">=$(=Date(YearStart(Today(), -1), 'M/D/YYYY'))<=$(=Date(AddYears(Today(), -1) - 1, 'M/D/YYYY'))"} >} [Revenue])
```

The keys points here:

- The [`YearStart()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2023/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/DateAndTimeFunctions/yearstart.htm) can be used to get the date value for the very beginning moment of the year of the provided date. The second parameter, `period_no`, lets you choose a future or previous year, relative to the specified date. In this case, the `-1` we use is saying to return the first day of one previous year from the `[DatePrest]` date.
- The [`Date()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/May2023/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/FormattingFunctions/Date.htm) needs to use the date format that matches the format used by the `[DatePrest]` field. In my examples above, I'm using the `M/D/YYYY` format because that's the format I tested it with, but you just need to make sure that those formats match.